# How to resolve this error TransactionException: commit failed?

Tags: ajax, hibernate, web-services, maven, spring-mvc

i have a Post request ajax like this :

```
$.ajax({
           "url":serverPath+"/taxiws/clients",
           "type": "POST",
           contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "text",
           "data": JSON.stringify(obj),
           "success": function(data) {
               console.log("success!!!");
            $("#LoadingBackgroundPopup").hide();
            window.location.href="reservationclient.html";

},"error": function(error) {
console.log(error);
}
});
```

method Post in web service:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<String> createFromJson(@RequestBody String json, UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        System.out.println("hello post");
        try {
            Client client = Client.fromJsonToClient(json);
            BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
            String hashedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(client.getPassword());

            client.setPassword(hashedPassword);
            System.out.println("Passowrd hashé    "+hashedPassword);
            client.persist();
            RequestMapping a = (RequestMapping) getClass().getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class);
            headers.add("Location",uriBuilder.path(a.value()[0]+"/"+client.getIdclient().toString()).build().toUriString());
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<String>("{\"ERROR\":"+e.getMessage()+"\"}", headers, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

but when i excute this requet i found this problem :

```
!JavaScript LOG: {"ERROR":org.hibernate.TransactionException: commit failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.TransactionException: commit failed"}
```

i added this command line e.getStackTrace(); in my web service ,i found this issue:

```
2016-04-14 11:56:57,043 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] ERROR org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AnnotationTransactionAspect - Application exception overridden by rollback exception
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:321)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.aspectj.JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect.ajc$afterThrowing$org_springframework_orm_jpa_aspectj_JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect$1$18a1ac9(JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect.aj:33)
    at com.binov.webservice.web.Client.persist_aroundBody26(Client.java:243)
    at com.binov.webservice.web.Client$AjcClosure27.run(Client.java:1)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96cproceed(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:59)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect$AbstractTransactionAspect$1.proceedWithInvocation(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:65)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96c(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:63)
    at com.binov.webservice.web.Client.persist(Client.java:241)
    at com.binov.webservice.ClientController.createFromJson(ClientController.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleSimpleCORS(CorsFilter.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1187)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:241)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.persist(Unknown Source)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3558)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:490)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "idclient" violates not-null constraint
  Détail : Failing row contains (null, 04-04-2016, dd@mail.com, dd, $2a$10$FXBRGcoZ3uFAD649LDgfMucLXveFDAF1NyrlCvdY6gjpUgpa/gfkO, dd, client, 1234567890, dd).
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2103)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1836)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:512)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:334)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
    ... 84 more
```

my classe client.java

```
   package com.binov.webservice.web;
import flexjson.JSONDeserializer;
import flexjson.JSONSerializer;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ReflectionToStringBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringStyle;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;



@Entity
@Table(schema = "public",name = "client")
@Configurable
public class Client {

    @Column(name = "datenaissance", length = 255)
    private String datenaissance;

    @Column(name = "email", length = 255)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "nom", length = 255)
    private String nom;

    @Column(name = "password", length = 255)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "prenom", length = 255)
    private String prenom;

    @Column(name = "role", length = 255)
    private String role;

    @Column(name = "telephone", length = 255)
    private String telephone;

    @Column(name = "username", length = 255)
    private String username;

    public String getDatenaissance() {
        return datenaissance;
    }

    public void setDatenaissance(String datenaissance) {
        this.datenaissance = datenaissance;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPrenom() {
        return prenom;
    }

    public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
        this.prenom = prenom;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public String getTelephone() {
        return telephone;
    }

    public void setTelephone(String telephone) {
        this.telephone = telephone;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idclient")
    private Integer idclient;

    public Integer getIdclient() {
        return this.idclient;
    }

    public void setIdclient(Integer id) {
        this.idclient = id;
    }

    @PersistenceContext
    transient EntityManager entityManager;

    public static final List<String> fieldNames4OrderClauseFilter = java.util.Arrays.asList("");

    public static final EntityManager entityManager() {
        EntityManager em = new Client().entityManager;
        if (em == null) throw new IllegalStateException("Entity manager has not been injected (is the Spring Aspects JAR configured as an AJC/AJDT aspects library?)");
        return em;
    }

    public String toJson() {
        return new JSONSerializer()
        .exclude("*.class").serialize(this);
    }

    public String toJson(String[] fields) {
        return new JSONSerializer()
        .include(fields).exclude("*.class").serialize(this);
    }

    public static Client fromJsonToClient(String json) {
        return new JSONDeserializer<Client>()
        .use(null, Client.class).deserialize(json);
    }

    public static String toJsonArray(Collection<Client> collection) {
        return new JSONSerializer()
        .exclude("*.class").serialize(collection);
    }

    public static String toJsonArray(Collection<Client> collection, String[] fields) {
        return new JSONSerializer()
        .include(fields).exclude("*.class").serialize(collection);
    }

    public static Collection<Client> fromJsonArrayToClients(String json) {
        return new JSONDeserializer<List<Client>>()
        .use("values", Client.class).deserialize(json);
    }




    public static long countClients() {
        return entityManager().createQuery("SELECT COUNT(o) FROM Client o", Long.class).getSingleResult();
    }

    public static List<Client> findAllClients() {
        return entityManager().createQuery("SELECT o FROM Client o", Client.class).getResultList();
    }

    public static List<Client> findAllClients(String sortFieldName, String sortOrder) {
        String jpaQuery = "SELECT o FROM Client o";
        if (fieldNames4OrderClauseFilter.contains(sortFieldName)) {
            jpaQuery = jpaQuery + " ORDER BY " + sortFieldName;
            if ("ASC".equalsIgnoreCase(sortOrder) || "DESC".equalsIgnoreCase(sortOrder)) {
                jpaQuery = jpaQuery + " " + sortOrder;
            }
        }
        return entityManager().createQuery(jpaQuery, Client.class).getResultList();
    }

    // find a client with her username and password

//      public static List<Client> findClientByUsernamePassword(String username,String password)
//      {
//          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//          if((username==null) && (password==null))return null;

//      return entityManager().createQuery("SELECT o FROM Client o where o.username=:username and o.password=:password", Client.class).setParameter("username", username).setParameter("password", password).getSingleResult();
//      }

        //find a cient by username  
        public static List<Client> findClientByUsernamePassword(String username)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if((username==null))return null;
            return (List<Client>) entityManager().createQuery("SELECT o FROM Client o WHERE o.username=:username",Client.class).setParameter("username", username).getResultList(); 

        }


        public static List<Client> findClientByUsernamePassword(String username2,String password2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return entityManager().createQuery("SELECT o FROM Client o where o.username=:username and o.password=:password", Client.class).setParameter("username", username2).setParameter("password", password2).getResultList();
        }





    public static Client findClient(Integer idclient) {
        if (idclient == null) return null;
        return entityManager().find(Client.class, idclient);
    }

    public static List<Client> findClientEntries(int firstResult, int maxResults) {
        return entityManager().createQuery("SELECT o FROM Client o", Client.class).setFirstResult(firstResult).setMaxResults(maxResults).getResultList();
    }

    public static List<Client> findClientEntries(int firstResult, int maxResults, String sortFieldName, String sortOrder) {
        String jpaQuery = "SELECT o FROM Client o";
        if (fieldNames4OrderClauseFilter.contains(sortFieldName)) {
            jpaQuery = jpaQuery + " ORDER BY " + sortFieldName;
            if ("ASC".equalsIgnoreCase(sortOrder) || "DESC".equalsIgnoreCase(sortOrder)) {
                jpaQuery = jpaQuery + " " + sortOrder;
            }
        }
        return entityManager().createQuery(jpaQuery, Client.class).setFirstResult(firstResult).setMaxResults(maxResults).getResultList();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void persist() {
        if (this.entityManager == null) this.entityManager = entityManager();
        this.entityManager.persist(this);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void remove() {
        if (this.entityManager == null) this.entityManager = entityManager();
        if (this.entityManager.contains(this)) {
            this.entityManager.remove(this);
        } else {
            Client attached = Client.findClient(this.idclient);
            this.entityManager.remove(attached);
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    public void flush() {
        if (this.entityManager == null) this.entityManager = entityManager();
        this.entityManager.flush();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void clear() {
        if (this.entityManager == null) this.entityManager = entityManager();
        this.entityManager.clear();
    }

    @Transactional
    public Client merge() {
        if (this.entityManager == null) this.entityManager = entityManager();
        Client merged = this.entityManager.merge(this);
        this.entityManager.flush();
        return merged;
    }

//  public String toString() {
//        return ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(this, ToStringStyle.SHORT_PREFIX_STYLE);
//    }

    public String toString() {
        return new ReflectionToStringBuilder(this, ToStringStyle.SHORT_PREFIX_STYLE).setExcludeFieldNames("Client").toString();
    }


}
```

please ,How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Make e.printStackTrace() and add the trace to the question.

Comment: The ConstraintViolationException is the important part. Seems that you have some sort of constraint in your class which breaks. Can't tell you what it is exactly can you add the Client class? A possibility is @NotNull but there are others too.

Comment: please look i added it

Comment: Print out the json and check if there's a field with more than 255 characters. I am quit shure that there's at least one with more than 255 characters which creates the constraint exception.

Comment: i solved this error of not null but always i found commit failed and this line e.getStackTrace();  don't found any result

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand what you mean. But I don't see anything related to the 255 characters.

Comment: thanks i solved my problem